Shopware: You have requested a non-existent service "form.factory"
I'm attempting to update from Shopware 6.4 to 6.5 and encountering the following error: You have requested a non-existent service "form.factory".
This error occurs when using $form = $this->createForm(ProductRequestType::class); from symfony/forms inside a StorefrontController.
I've cleared the cache and confirmed that symfony/forms is installed, but the issue persists.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
